# Meteor live update doesn't work as expected

Tags: meteor

When I make changes to the database that affect UserProfiles, the client side is updated. For instance, if I change a weekday from true to false the UserProfile will appear or disappear on my computer screen. However, when I make a change to Attendances, for instance, create a new attendance record which should make a UserProfile appear nothing happens unless I reload the page. I assume it's to do with studnentUserIds not being rerun.

How do I make Meteor notice these changes?

This is being built using Meteor, React and mongoDB.

```
Meteor.publish('teacher.AdminDashboardContainer.userProfiles', function getStudentUserProfiles(rollCallDate) {
  if (this.userId) {
    const start = new Date(moment(rollCallDate).startOf('day').toISOString());
    const end = new Date(moment(rollCallDate).endOf('day').toISOString());
    const weekday = `student.days.${moment(rollCallDate).format('dddd').toLowerCase()}`;

    const studentUserIds = Attendances.find({
      $and: [
        { createdAt: { $gte: start, $lt: end } },
      ],
    }).map(attendance => attendance.studentUserProfileId);

    return UserProfiles.find({
        $or: [
          { _id: { $in: studentUserIds } },
          {
            $and: [
              { [weekday]: true },
            ],
          },
        ],
      }),
  }
  // user not authorized. do not publish secrets
  this.stop();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This type of functionality is commonly referred to as a `reactive join`. There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but take into account that those solutions tend to be computationally expensive.

Answer (score 0):

How about using publish-composite? It handles the "reactivity" part on its own. 
https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite